# Use blender particle system on terrain that has been displaced using displacement node. 2.8

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, hair, displacement, procedural

I created a very substantial procedural system that creates everything procedurally. I went to add the rocks, grass, and leaves to the terrain using the particle system. But when I went to render, everything was beneath the terrain. I cannot use the displacement modifier, so do not suggest. I am using cycles on 2.8.